# How to bake Freestyle, or snap Brush to UV or edge?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I want to draw srtright line on my model, like a fresstyle, but I need this lines on texture. I wanted to bake Freestyle, but it seems like it is impossible, so may be I can snap brush to edge on the model or to the edge on the UV? I know that I can use "Pointness" node, but I need to choose needed edges by myself.

[image]

Edited: temporary, not completely solution:
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at drawing grease pencil snapped to the surface? GP can then be baked into the texture if converted to geometry and using AO bake I believe.

Comment: @CraigDJones I never used Greace Pencil. I was think that it will be easier